# Cascading dropdown - Dataset

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, npm, dropdown

In my form I want to create cascading dropdown where logic will be like this ->
User will select value from 1. dropdown then data in second dropdown will change, after selecting value from 2. dropdown data will change in 3. dropdown.

My question is, what is the best way to build data set from which I will be getting data ?
Now I have 3 array object like this ->

```
export const dropdown1 = [
{key: 1, value: 'something'}
]

export const dropdown2 = [
{key: 1, value: 'something else'}
]

export const dropdown3 = [
{key: 1, value: 'something else else'}
]
```

I already create dropdown component and imported in main component, where can get data but don't know how to make it to cascading and first trying to figureout dataset of this dropdown columns.

Comment: Hi @jck4real, in which storage service does your dataset has been stored.

Answer (score 0):

I have create a react application as per your requirement check below.

- Combine the arrays into a structured dataset that represents the hierarchical relationship.
- Attach event handler to the dropdowns to handle user interactions and trigger the cascading behavior.

```js
// Event handler for state selection
  const handleStateChange = event => {
    setSelectedState(event.target.value);
    setSelectedCity('');
  };

// Event handler for city selection
  const handleCityChange = event => {
    setSelectedCity(event.target.value);
  };
```

- we use React hooks (useState) to manage the selected state and city. The **handleStateChange** and **handleCityChange** functions update the selected state and city respectively. The cities and areas are dynamically populated based on the selected state and city using the map function.

Here is the below code that works for me.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

// Sample dataset for states, cities, and areas
const dataset = [
  { stateKey: 1, stateValue: 'California', cityKey: 1, cityValue: 'Los Angeles', areaKey: 1, areaValue: 'Downtown' },
  { stateKey: 1, stateValue: 'California', cityKey: 1, cityValue: 'Los Angeles', areaKey: 2, areaValue: 'Hollywood' },
  { stateKey: 1, stateValue: 'California', cityKey: 2, cityValue: 'San Francisco', areaKey: 3, areaValue: 'Downtown' },
  { stateKey: 1, stateValue: 'California', cityKey: 2, cityValue: 'San Francisco', areaKey: 4, areaValue: 'Fisherman\'s Wharf' },
  { stateKey: 2, stateValue: 'New York', cityKey: 3, cityValue: 'New York City', areaKey: 5, areaValue: 'Manhattan' },
  { stateKey: 2, stateValue: 'New York', cityKey: 3, cityValue: 'New York City', areaKey: 6, areaValue: 'Brooklyn' },
  // Add more data as needed
];

const DropdownExample = () => {
  const [selectedState, setSelectedState] = useState('');
  const [selectedCity, setSelectedCity] = useState('');

  // Filter cities based on selected state
  const cities = dataset
    .filter(item => item.stateValue === selectedState)
    .map(item => item.cityValue);

  // Filter areas based on selected city
  const areas = dataset
    .filter(item => item.cityValue === selectedCity)
    .map(item => item.areaValue);

  // Event handler for state selection
  const handleStateChange = event => {
    setSelectedState(event.target.value);
    setSelectedCity('');
  };

  // Event handler for city selection
  const handleCityChange = event => {
    setSelectedCity(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <select value={selectedState} onChange={handleStateChange}>
        <option value="">Select State</option>
        <option value="California">California</option>
        <option value="New York">New York</option>
        {/* Add more state options as needed */}
      </select>

      <select value={selectedCity} onChange={handleCityChange}>
        <option value="">Select City</option>
        {cities.map(city => (
          <option key={city} value={city}>{city}</option>
        ))}
      </select>

      <select>
        <option value="">Select Area</option>
        {areas.map(area => (
          <option key={area} value={area}>{area}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DropdownExample;
```

**Result :**

[image]

> I want to create cascading dropdown where logic will be like this -> User will select value from 1. dropdown then data in second dropdown will change, after selecting value from 2. dropdown data will change in 3. dropdown.

[image]